# Can't read database information in Android

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to read data from a **SQL** database. I think my code is right but some how I can't display in a **text box**. The app just closes when I use the function `compareData()`.

(I have different alarms. I want to read all of them and display their id and name.)

Here is my code:

```
public class RingAlarm extends Activity {

TextView texto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ring_alarm);

    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    texto.setText(compareData());
}

public String compareData(){
    String result = "";
    String str1 = "";
    String str2 = "";

    String[] columns = new String[]{Database.COLUMN_ALARM_ID, Database.COLUMN_ALARM_NAME};

    Cursor cursor = Database.getDatabase().query(Database.ALARM_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        str1 = str1 + cursor.getString(0);
        str2 = str2 + cursor.getString(1);
        result = result + str1 + " - " + str2 + "\n";
    }

    cursor.close();

    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: try printing some logs. Are you getting something in the result.

Comment: Please post exception stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should not do Database I/O on the Main UI Thread as this can cause the application to hang and crash.

Using an AsyncTask is the simplest solution for what you're doing. The AsyncTask allows you to perform longer running tasks such as querying a database or network I/O in the background without disrupting the UI.

The following code incorporates your compareData() method into the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask. The TextView can then be set in the onPostExecute method using the result returned from doInBackground(). All computation should be done in doInBackground() and the UI objects should be set in onPostExecute(). To perform this task in your onCreate() you simply instantiate the task and call .execute().

```
public class RingAlarm extends Activity {

    TextView texto;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ring_alarm);

        MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute();
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        /**
         * The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
         * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute()
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String result = "";
            String str1 = "";
            String str2 = "";

            String[] columns = new String[]{Database.COLUMN_ALARM_ID, Database.COLUMN_ALARM_NAME};

            Cursor cursor = Database.getDatabase().query(Database.ALARM_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                str1 = str1 + cursor.getString(0);
                str2 = str2 + cursor.getString(1);
                result = result + str1 + " - " + str2 + "\n";
            }

            cursor.close();

            return result;
        }

        /**
        * The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
        * the result from doInBackground()
        */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            texto.setText(result);    
        }
    }

}
```

This link explains fully how AsyncTask works: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Hope this helps!